# Weird circular dependencies after updating to AngularDart 0.10.0

Tags: dart, angular-dart

After updating from AngularDart 0.9.9 to 0.10.0 I encountered weird error messages:

Cannot resolve a circular dependency! (resolving ElementProbe -> ElementProbe -> ElementProbe...

The stack trace doesn't contain any method or class of mine, except applicationFactory().run();

What has happened, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/961.
You need to ensure you have di version 0.0.40 which contains a fix.

Answer (score 0):

No idea whether it's a good idea what I did to fix the error, but here is my solution:

I suspect pub update didn't delete every old class. So I deleted the every package in the packages folder, and ran pub get again.

Comment: You should use `pub upgrade`. `pub get` only ensures that the dependencies in `pubspec.lock` are available. If no `pubspec.lock` exists `pub get` and `pub upgrade` do the same thing.